# Uso de string dá erro

Tags: c++, string

No inicio do código eu declaro a variável `nome` como `char` e quando tento pegar a variável `nome` lá em baixo no código dá erro, eu já tentei de várias formas e dessa forma que esta ai em baixo até dá certo, mas as vezes quando aparece a pergunta pro usuário " Deseja continuar ? " e ele responde s (sim), às vezes pula direto pro campo "digite o salario do funcionário:", ou seja. pula a parte em que pergunta o nome do funcionário

```
int cont, tinss;

char s, resp, nome[50];

float sal, novosala, val; 

cont = 1;

do
{
    printf("\n digite o nome do funcionario; ");
    scanf("%s",&nome);
    printf("\n digite o salario do funcionario: ");
    scanf("%f",&sal);

    if(sal <= 500)
        {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 8);
            val = (sal / 100) * 8;
            tinss = 8;              
        }
    else
    if(sal > 500 &&  sal <= 1000)
        {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 10);
            val = (sal / 100) * 10;
            tinss = 10; 
        }
    else
    if(sal > 1000)
        {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 12);
            val = (sal / 100) * 12;
            tinss = 12;
        }


    printf("\n Nome: %s \n",nome);
    printf("\n Salario bruto: %f \n", sal);
    printf("\n Taxa de INSS: %d% \n", tinss);
    printf("\n Valor de INSS %f \n", val);
    printf("\n Salario liquido: %f \n", novosala);

    printf("\n deseja continuar ? \n");
    resp = getch();
    cont = cont + 1;
}
while(resp == 's');
```

Comment: Note que, no seu programa em concreto, `else if(sal > 1000)` pode ser substituído por apenas `else`.

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Seu código está em C e não C++. Troque scanf("%s",&nome); por scanf("%s", nome);, pois nome já é o endereço da posição inicial do array, e também reveja o uso da função getch. Verifique se o buffer de entrada não está ficando com sujeira após a leitura de resp.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro, você pode até estar usando um compilador C++ mas você está programando em C. E está usando uma função que não deveria ser usada mais. Elimine a `getch()` e o problema será resolvido.

Tem outras funções que podem ser usadas mas eu usaria o `scanf()` até para não ficar esquisito hora ter que dar o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, hora não.

Então ficaria assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char resp;
    do {
    int cont = 1, tinss;
    char s, nome[50];
    float sal, novosala, val;
    printf("\n digite o nome do funcionario; ");
        scanf("%s",&nome);
        printf("\n digite o salario do funcionario: ");
        scanf("%f",&sal);
        if (sal <= 500) {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 8);
            val = (sal / 100) * 8;
            tinss = 8;              
        } else if (sal > 500 &&  sal <= 1000) {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 10);
            val = (sal / 100) * 10;
            tinss = 10; 
        } else if (sal > 1000) {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 12);
            val = (sal / 100) * 12;
            tinss = 12;
        }
        printf("\n Nome: %s \n",nome);
        printf("\n Salario bruto: %f \n", sal);
        printf("\n Taxa de INSS: %d% \n", tinss);
        printf("\n Valor de INSS %f \n", val);
        printf("\n Salario liquido: %f \n", novosala);
        printf("\n deseja continuar ? \n");
        scanf("%s",&resp);
        cont = cont + 1;
    } while (resp == 's');
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/eCqFjw). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/jgfpfbod-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Inss.c).

Versão mais C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string  resp;
    do {
        int cont = 1, tinss;
        string s, nome;
        float sal, novosala, val; 
        cout << endl << "digite o nome do funcionario: ";
        cin >> nome;
        cout << endl << "digite o salario do funcionario: ";
        cin >> sal;
        if (sal <= 500) {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 8);
            val = (sal / 100) * 8;
            tinss = 8;              
        } else if (sal > 500 &&  sal <= 1000) {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 10);
            val = (sal / 100) * 10;
            tinss = 10; 
        } else if(sal > 1000) {
            novosala = sal - ((sal / 100) * 12);
            val = (sal / 100) * 12;
            tinss = 12;
        }
        cout << endl << "Nome: " << nome << endl;
        cout << "Salario bruto: " << sal << endl;
        cout << "Taxa de INSS: " << tinss << endl;
        cout << "Valor de INSS " << val << endl;
        cout << "Salario liquido: " << novosala << endl;
        cout << endl << "deseja continuar ? " << endl;
        cin >> resp;
        cont++;
    }
    while (resp == "s");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](http://ideone.com/FXq0Y1). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/vgxjyjmh-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/Inss.cpp).

Dá para fazer melhor mas já está mais organizado.